# Spring Boot - OneToMany and save entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

We have 2 entity Account and Transfer with relationship one to many. Now I try to save Transfer to my database so I create a view with needed fields and pass `iban_sender` to have connector.

I'll try to simplify my problem to make it more comfortable to read.

Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "iban", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String iban;
    @Column(name = "balance", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private float balance;
    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreated;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Transfer> transfers;

    public Account(){}

    public Account(String iban, float balance, Date dateCreated,User user) {
        this.iban = iban;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Transfer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_transfer")
public class Transfer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "iban_receiver", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String ibanReceiver;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "receiver", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String receiver;
    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private float amount;
    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "iban_sender")
    private Account account;


    public Transfer(){}

    public Transfer(String ibanReceiver, String title, String receiver, float amount, Date dateCreated, Account account) {
        this.ibanReceiver = ibanReceiver;
        this.title = title;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

AccountController.java

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    private final TransferService transferService;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(TransferService transferService) {
        this.transferService = transferService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/transfer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String transferForm(HttpServletRequest request,Authentication authentication){
        CurrentUser currentUser = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Set<Account> accounts = currentUser.getAccounts();
        String FirstIban = accounts.iterator().next().getIban(); // TODO: Make a list of accounts

        request.setAttribute("iban_sender",FirstIban);
        return "account_transfer";
    }
    //TODO: create view of all accounts

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/transfer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerTrasnform(@Valid Transfer transfer, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "account_transfer";
        }
        System.out.println("LOGI -- transfer" + transfer.toString());
        transferService.save(transfer);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

And finally my view:

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="_csrf" type="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="error" type="java.util.Optional<String>" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Make transfer</h1>

<form role="form" action="/account/transfer" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

    <div>
        <label for="iban_sender">Account number</label>
        <input type="text" name="iban_sender" id="iban_sender" value="${iban_sender}" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="iban_receiver">Account number</label>
        <input type="text" name="ibanReceiver" id="iban_receiver" required autofocus/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="receiver">Receiver</label>
        <input type="text" name="receiver" id="receiver" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

My error:

> ERROR 1456 --- [nio-8080-exec-9]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'iban_sender' cannot
>   be null ERROR 1456 --- [nio-8080-exec-9]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement] with root cause

Error trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'iban_sender' cannot be null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.persist(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:394)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.save(Unknown Source)
at com.ematkuz.ebank.service.transfer.TransferServiceImpl.save(TransferServiceImpl.java:25)
at com.ematkuz.ebank.controller.AccountController.registerTrasnform(AccountController.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Seems that spring do not recognize connector column iban_sender. My questions are:
1. What am I doing wrong ?
2. Can I take from my view iban_sender? That would solve the problem because I could create Transform object.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to save an instance of `Transfer` before assigning an instance of `Account` to it. Could you provide the full stack trace please?

Comment: That's exactly what happens but I don't know how to solve this in easy way. Error trace added.

Comment: Does your instance of `Transfer` not have a reference to an instance of `Account` or is that reference not yet saved to the database?

Comment: Instance of Account was saved to database. Transfer not have a reference to an instance of Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the Account object when saving Account transfer.

One of the solutions could be:

```
//Will not persist in database 
@Transient
private int ibanSenderId;

Account account = //fetch using tranfer.getIbanSenderId() from database

transfer.setAccount(account);

transferService.save(transfer);
```